# How can I change the contents of an include file without recompiling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I have inherited an application that has some hardcoded values stored in a config.js file.
for discussion purposes, i'll use this example:

**main.js**

```
let bWidgets = true;

select (case window.location.hostname) {
     case 'abc.mydomain.com':
          VARIABLE1 = "this should be more dynamic"
          VARIABLE2 = "so should this"
          break;
     case 'ddd.mydomain.com':
          VARIABLE1 = "now its set to something else."
          VARIABLE2 = "blah"
          break;
}
```

**Problem**

This app will ultimately end up as a docker image and I'd like to be able to dynamically change / pass new values to the nodejs application / running docker container without having to do an npm run build just because a string has changed.

I was thinking of creating an include file of some sort.  But if the file type is js, then I still need to rebuild it.

**main.js**

```
let bWidgets = true;
require("./abcdomain.js")
```

**new abcdomain.js**

```
VARIABLE1 = "this should be more dynamic"
VARIABLE2 = "so should this"
```

But by virtue of the fact that it's still a js file, I believe i still have to npm run build right?
can i include as a text instead?

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm going to use the dotenv package.
create a separate env file for each scenario.
And then save it in a mount for the running docker instance.
The node app itself will just always include .ENV file...